# Sourcing a config file in bash

Tags: bash

I know I can `source FILE` or `. FILE` a file in Bash, but for some reason I cannot get it to load in the file. I keep seeing "No such file or directory" errors in the console.

Here's the directory structure

```
/bin/script.sh (file including the config)
/config.sh
```

I may re-structure this anyways, but for now, I think it is what it is. I'm attempting to include the config file like this:

```
source ../config.sh
source config.sh
```

Neither one of those actually works. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe there's a better way to get the path, relative to the script being executed?

Comment: You're in the wrong directory?

Comment: Well that's kind of the issue. Theoretically the `script.sh` can be executed from just about anywhere on the system. It doesn't really matter where you execute `script.sh` from...as long as you can supply a correct path to the script to execute it. That's my thinking anyways.

Comment: This works... if `../config.sh`/`config.sh` is relative to `$PWD`. [You might want to look at this for a lead in the right direction.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Answer (score 4):

Aaron's response totally helped out. This is the solution that ended up working for me.

```
SCRIPTDIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
source $SCRIPTDIR/../config.sh;
```

Comment: Glad to help. I really didn't have time to answer it myself.

Comment: Yeah, getting the path from within the script was an all-around win. That worked beautifully!

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/028](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).